# Process keeps old console title after releasing allocated console

Tags: c++, winapi, console-application

I'm trying to change the name of the process after i release the console, the problem is even when I change the title just before the FreeConsole call it still has the old title. Example: Set title to 'abc' => do code => Set title to 'xyz' => FreeConsole. The title still says 'abc'. Here's how I do it in form of an example:

```
void setup_console_example()
{
    AllocConsole();
    GetConsoleTitleA(old_console_title, 1024); // Let's say it was "xyz"
    SetConsoleTitleA("abc");
    /* ... */
    SetConsoleTitleA(old_console_title); // example 1
    SetWindowTextA(FindWindowA(nullptr, "abc"), old_console_title); // example 2
    FreeConsole();
    /* program is called "abc" in task manager even after setting another title*/
}
```

I would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

I tested the *SetConsoleTitle* [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsoletitle#examples). It works for me except needing to reopen TaskManager per *SetConsoleTitle*.